# How to turn the center of the X Y coordinates of a SVG object to the center of the plane?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a circle and a SVG plane:

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g class="point" transform="translate(6.5,1)">
     <g class="delete-point" transform="translate(11,-11)"></g>
     <circle></circle>
     <text class="point-index" y="4"><tspan text-anchor="middle">0</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And this is how I'm getting x and y of the circle:

```
          d3.selectAll('.point')
            .each(function() {
              var c = d3.select(this)
              var cX = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[0]
              var cY = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[1]
              list.push({ x: Math.round(cX), y: Math.round(cY), index: k++ })
            }
```

Right now 0 of X and Y are in the top left corner. How to do it so that the 0 of X and Y are in the middle of the plane?

Note: `.point` is the circle and `svg` is the plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the origin of the SVG file by using a translate transform:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(200 200)">

    <!-- coordinate (0,0) is now in the center of the SVG -->
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="150" fill="red"/>
    
  </g>
</svg>
```